# Javascript variable not rendering in another javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a shopping cart platform that has some variable already defined in a script tag... the one I need being product code.

to test the variable working, I put:

```
<script>
    console.log(global_Current_ProductCode);
</script>
```

and in console, it returns the product code correctly depending on what product page is on, so far so good!

Next, I have another javascript code for a platform implementation (Power Reviews) and it looks like this:

```
<script>
    POWERREVIEWS.display.render({
        api_key: 'xxx-key-xxx',
        locale: 'en_US',
        merchant_group_id: 'xxxx',
        merchant_id: 'xxxx',
        page_id: 'global_Current_ProductCode',
        review_wrapper_url: 'https://www.myurlhere.com/Articles.asp?ID=265',
        components: {
            ReviewSnippet: 'pr-reviewsnippet',
            ReviewDisplay: 'pr-reviewdisplay'
        }
    });
</script>
```

(I added global_Current_ProductCode) and it just writes out: **global_Current_ProductCode** when page is rendered, so it's not calling the variable.  But adding the variable to a console log DOES work. Am I missing something?

Comment: `'document.write(global_Current_ProductCode);'` you wrote it as a string literal. And your latest edit still is a string literal `'global_Current_ProductCode'` remove the quotes if you want JS to use the actual variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page_id: 'global_Current_ProductCode',` should be `page_id: global_Current_ProductCode,`

Using quotes (single or double quotes) makes it a String literal, not a variable, so the variable's value is not used.
Remove the single quotes.